# How do I tell I find all AWS metrics using high-resolution?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, micrometer, spring-micrometer

i run into this error in AWS cloudwatch

[image]

which does not make sense as I think/thought we had 0 high resolution metrics(high resolution only records for 3 hours).  We typically just do 1 minute interval reporting.  How do I find all metrics with high resolution?  In this way I am hoping I can edit them to not high resolution.

I searched around a ton on the documentation and I looked into micrometer code which seems to default to highResolution = false and a step of 2 minutes.  (We are using micrometer).  I am trying to figure out next steps on figuring out why AWS thinks this data is high resolution data.

I was also thinking 'ok, perhaps it would roll up to 1 minute data then 5 minute data' so in my query I tried 1 minute and 5 minute but I still get the error of only 3 hours of data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error is thrown because you're using the query syntax (`SELECT ...`) and that only supports the latest 3 hours of data. The feature is called Metrics Insights, you can see the limits here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-metrics-insights-limits.html

Error is not related to high resolution metrics. Even if they were high resolution, when you're setting the period to 5 min, you would only retrieve datapoints aggregated to 5 min granularity.